# Dragging table data to other cell using jscript

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am new to jQuery programming and I was trying to make a chess game. I just want to ask help from you on how can I make my pieces move when I drag them. Here a part of my code. You can also see the other part in my fiddle code (posted the link below):

```
<table id="chess_board" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="A8"><a href="#" class="rookBlack">&#9820;</a></td>
        <td id="B8"><a href="#" class="nightBlack">&#9822;</a></td>
        <td id="C8"><a href="#" class="bishopBlack">&#9821;</a></td>
        <td id="D8"><a href="#" class="kingBlack">&#9819;</a></td>
        <td id="E8"><a href="#" class="queenBlack">&#9818;</a></td>
        <td id="F8"><a href="#" class="bishopBlack">&#9821;</a></td>
        <td id="G8"><a href="#" class="nightBlack">&#9822;</a></td>
        <td id="H8"><a href="#" class="rookBlack">&#9820;</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="A7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
        <td id="B7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
        <td id="C7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
        <td id="D7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
        <td id="E7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
        <td id="F7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
        <td id="G7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
        <td id="H7"><a href="#" class="pawnBlack">&#9823;</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Please see my code :http://jsfiddle.net/JKFKC/61/embedded/result/

Comment: try using `http://jqueryui.com/draggable/` and `http://jqueryui.com/droppable/`

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JcL7s/

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do if you just use the jQuery library by referenceing on your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

and then in your Javascript just call the .Draggable function on anything you want to be able to drag. Simple as that:

```
$("a").draggable();  // this would make any `a` tag draggable.
```

Here is the link to the draggable functionality in jQuery: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Also look into the droppable functionality that they provide as well: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

Add this Script

```
$(function() {
    $( "a" ).draggable();
  });
```

[Here you can Downlaod the Jquery Draggable Code](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js)

Here you Go  **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JKFKC/62/)**

---

**[Here New answer](http://jsfiddle.net/JKFKC/65/)**

Dude add this code

```
$('a').draggable({ containment: "table", revert: 'invalid' });

$('td').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(droppedOn).droppable("disable");
        $(dropped).parent().droppable("enable");
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0, left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});   
$('td').not('td:empty').droppable("disable");
```

Comment: sir how can i make it stick to the table whenever i release the click function?

Comment: @user1998735 find out new answer dude

Comment: hi sir i tried this but whenever i drag the piece i get this http://tinypic.com/r/wtuloj/5 a link appears instead of the data from the cell

Comment: @user1998735  ohh is it??? Once gain you try the same code. Its absolutly fine dude.